# ArgumentOutOfRange in List when using method RemoveRange

Tags: c#, .net, linq

So I have a list which contains 379 elements and I want to delete last 8 of them

I'm using

```
List<Point> points= new List<Point>();
...
points.RemoveRange(points.Count-8,8);
```

but it throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`:

> Non-negative number required. Parameter name:index

So class where I have list looks like this

```
namespace XanMan.NET
{
    class PointsMap
    {
        List<Point> points = new List<Point>();

        public PointsMap()
        {
            float x = 80;
            float y = 655;
            for (int i=0;i<28;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                x += 20;
            }
            x = 680;
            for (int i=0;i<26;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                x += 20;
            }
            x = 80;
            y = 55;
            for (int i=0;i<56;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                x += 20;
            }
            x = 50;
            y = 455;
            for (int i=0;i<14;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                x += 20;
            }
            x = 405;
            for (int i=0;i<22;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                x += 20;
            }
            x = 880;
            for (int i=0;i<18;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                x += 20;
            }
            y = 215;
            x = 55;
            for (int i=0;i<15;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                x += 20;
            }
            x = 400;
            for (int i=0;i<16;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                x += 20;
            }
            x = 880;
            for (int i=0;i<18;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                x += 20;
            }
            x = 760;
            y = 335;
            for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                x += 20;
            }
            x = 880;
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                x += 20;
            }
            x = 55;
            y = 80;
            for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                y += 20;
            }
            x = 375;
            y = 80;
            for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                y += 20;
            }
            y = 80;
            x = 535;
            for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                y += 20;
            }
            y = 80;
            x = 735;
            for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                y += 20;
            }
            x = 895;
            y = 80;
            for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                y += 20;
            }
            x = 1215;
            y = 80;
            for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                y += 20;
            }
            y = 240;
            x = 175;
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                y += 20;
            }
            y = 240;
            x = 375;
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                y += 20;
            }
            y = 240;
            x = 535;
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                y += 20;
            }
            y = 240;
            x = 735;
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                y += 20;
            }
            x = 855;
            y = 240;
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                y += 20;
            }
            y = 240;
            x = 1095;
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                y += 20;
            }
            for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                y += 20;
            }
            x = 855;
            y = 480;
            for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                y += 20;
            }
            x = 1215;
            y = 480;
            for (int i=0;i<8;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                y += 20;
            }
            y = 215;
            x = 720;
            for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                x += 20;
            }
            y = 455;
            x = 330;
            for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
            {
                points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(x, y)));
                x += 20;
            }

            points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(50, 50)));
            points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(1210, 50)));
            points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(50, 650)));
            points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(1210, 650)));
            points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(370, 450)));
            points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(370, 210)));
            points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(850, 210)));
            points.Add(new Point(new Vector2f(850, 450)));
        }

        public void Draw(RenderWindow window)
        {
            points.RemoveRange(points.Count - 8, 8);
            foreach (Point point in points)
            {
                point.Draw(window);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

class Point:

```
namespace XanMan.NET
{
    class Point
    {
        protected Texture texture;
        protected RectangleShape body;
        protected Vector2f position;
        public const uint point = 10;

        public Point(Vector2f position)
        {
            texture = new Texture("point.png");
            body = new RectangleShape(new Vector2f(10, 10))
            {
                Texture = texture,
                Position = position
        };

        }
        protected Point()
        {
        }

        public void Draw(RenderWindow window)
        {
            window.Draw(body);
        }
    }
}
```

And program.cs with main

```
class Program
{
    static RenderWindow window;
    static GAMESTATE gamestate;
    static Map map;
    static Menu menu;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        window = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(1280, 780), "XanMan.NET");
        gamestate = GAMESTATE.mainmenu;
         menu = new Menu(gamestate);
        map = new Map();
        PointsMap mapOfPoints = new PointsMap();
        window.Closed += Window_Closed;
        window.KeyReleased += menu.Update;


        while (window.IsOpen)
        {
            window.DispatchEvents();
            window.Clear();
            map.Draw(window);
            mapOfPoints.Draw(window);
            window.Display();
        }
    }

    private static void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e) => window.Close();
}
```

I've deleted some of loops in PointsMap because of stackoverflow, but You've got the idea of what's going on.

Comment: Works fine for me.  You need to post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It sounds like the list contains fewer elements than you expect. Did you set a break point on that line and debug to that line and check the Count value to be sure?

Comment: Before asking the question i have written in console how much elements I've got just one line before removing range and It shows 371 so everything was as expected. I thought maybe because i' ve add all elements in constructor, but constructor is before any other function in class so I don't know.

Comment: Your edit makes the question a little better, but it is still not an MCVE.  The code you've posted does not reproduce the issue, so the error is somewhere else in your code.  Ideally we should be able to copy/paste your MCVE into our IDE and get exactly the result you are seeing.

Comment: In debug in locals it shows me that count equals to 3. I'll copy all the code in a minute.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto If u mean x,y values, they are changing and It's intended.

Comment: `while (window.IsOpen)..... mapOfPoints.Draw`. `mmapOfPointsp.Draw` removes 8 items per iteration, in which iteration is this failing?

Comment: This is actually just a debug problem and you can use any number of techniques to highlight how this is going wrong. I would suggest using the debugger more with maybe conditional break points, and also writing your results to the console or output window to know what the state is of your program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your draw function assumes, that the removerange index and offset are multiples of 8.
That seems not be the case: points.Count % 8 != 0.
You could use the following code, which just takes care of the remaining rest.

```
    public void Draw(RenderWindow window)
    {
        var n = 8;
        var index = Math.Max(0, points.Count - n);
        var offset = Math.Min(points.Count, n);
        points.RemoveRange(index, offset);

        foreach (Point point in points)
        {
           point.Draw(window);
        }
     }
```